# anno_text function in Complex Heatmap, how to name row annotation in the top?

Tags: r, bioconductor, complexheatmap

I am struggling to modify a row annotation label from the bottom to the top of the column.

The function *anno_text* has the parameter *show_name = FALSE*. However, it does not have the parameter side (or name_side). As a consequence, the annotation label is always put at the bottom of the column.

Would anyone know how to change that?  I want to annotate at the top instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grid.text` to add annotations anywhere rather than `show_name = TRUE` in `anno_text()` directly, follow the guide [6.2.2 Add titles for row annotations](https://jokergoo.github.io/ComplexHeatmap-reference/book/heatmap-decoration.html#add-titles-for-row-annotations).